# Osculating Paraboloid equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, approximation

[image]

I know how to find tangent plane but I don't know about how to find osculating paraboloid and then approximate N.
Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the osculating paraboloid can be written as
$$
z=F(x,y)=a(x-1)^2+b(x-1)(y-1)+c(y-1)^2+d(x-1)+e(y-1)+1.
$$
You can find the coefficients by imposing that all partial derivatives of $F$, up to second order, are the same as the derivatives of $x^9y^7$ at $(1,1)$:
$$
{\partial F\over\partial x}(1,1)=
{\partial\over\partial x}(x^9y^7)\bigg\vert_{(1,1)}
\quad
{\partial F\over\partial y}(1,1)=
{\partial\over\partial y}(x^9y^7)\bigg\vert_{(1,1)}
$$
$$
{\partial^2 F\over\partial x^2}(1,1)=
{\partial^2\over\partial x^2}(x^9y^7)\bigg\vert_{(1,1)}
\quad
{\partial^2 F\over\partial x\partial y}(1,1)=
{\partial^2\over\partial x\partial y}(x^9y^7)\bigg\vert_{(1,1)}
\quad
{\partial^2 F\over\partial y^2}(1,1)=
{\partial^2\over\partial y^2}(x^9y^7)\bigg\vert_{(1,1)}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain more ? @Aretino about last comment you made?

Comment: See my edit........

Answer (score 0):

A paraboloid is a quadratic surface, i.e. of the form $z=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+z$, a quadratic polynomial in $x,y$.

For a paraboloid to be osculating, all its coefficients must match those of the Taylor development to the second order. (Similarly, the tangent plane is an osculating plane.)